# get count of records in every hour in the last 24 hour

Tags: sql, oracle, timespan

i need number of records in each hour in the last 24 hours, i need my query to show 0 if there are no records in any of the particular hour for that day, i am just able to get data for hours that are in table.

```
SELECT TRUNC(systemdate,'HH24') + (trunc(to_char(systemdate,'mi')/10)*10)/24/60 AS date1, 
 count(*) AS txncount
FROM transactionlog 
GROUP BY TRUNC(systemdate,'HH24') + (trunc(to_char(systemdate,'mi')/10)*10)/24/60 order by date1 desc;
```

result:

[image: result set]

What should i do to get data in each hour of the last 24 hours?

Expected data:

[image: expected data]

record count in each hour for last 24 hours , starting from current date time.. if no record exist in that particular hour, 0 is shown.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih added expected data

Comment: You can achieve what you are looking for by writing an _internal_ select that would retrieve all the records of the last 24 hours and then select the **HOUR** part of the datetime and **COUNT** records grouping by the result of the hour extraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might be what you need. It seems to work when I run it against the all_objects view.

```
WITH date_range
  AS (SELECT TRUNC(sysdate - (rownum/24),'HH24') as the_hour
        FROM dual
      CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 1000),
     the_data
  AS (SELECT TRUNC(created, 'HH24')  as cr_ddl, count(*) as num_obj
        FROM all_objects
      GROUP BY TRUNC(created, 'HH24'))   
SELECT TO_CHAR(dr.the_hour,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI AM'), NVL(num_obj,0)
FROM date_range dr LEFT OUTER JOIN the_data  ao
     ON ao.cr_ddl =  dr.the_hour
ORDER BY dr.the_hour DESC
```

The 'date_range' generates a record for each hour over the past 24.
The 'the_data' does a count of the number of records in your target table based on the date truncated to the hour.
The main query then outer joins the two of them showing the date and the count from the sub-query.
I prefer both parts of the query in their own CTE because it makes the actual query very obvious and 'clean'.

In terms of your query you want this;

```
WITH date_range
  AS (SELECT TRUNC(sysdate - (rownum/24),'HH24') as the_hour
        FROM dual
      CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 24),
     the_data
  AS (SELECT TRUNC(systemdate, 'HH24')  as log_date, count(*) as num_obj
        FROM transactionlog 
      GROUP BY TRUNC(systemdate, 'HH24'))   
SELECT TO_CHAR(dr.the_hour,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI AM'), NVL(trans_log.num_obj,0)
FROM date_range dr LEFT OUTER JOIN the_data  trans_log
     ON trans_log.log_date =  dr.the_hour
ORDER BY dr.the_hour DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
WITH transactionlog AS 
(
    SELECT TO_DATE('03/05/2018 01:12','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') AS systemdate, 60 AS value 
    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT TO_DATE('03/05/2018 01:32','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 35 FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT TO_DATE('03/05/2018 09:44','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 31 FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT TO_DATE('03/05/2018 08:56','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 24 FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT TO_DATE('03/05/2018 08:02','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 98 FROM dual 
)
, time_range AS 
(
    SELECT TRUNC(sysdate, 'hh24') - 23/24 + (ROWNUM - 1) / 24 AS time1
    FROM all_objects
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 24
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(r.time1, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi AM') AS date1,
    COUNT(t.systemdate) AS txncount
FROM time_range r
LEFT JOIN transactionlog t
ON r.time1 = TRUNC(t.systemdate, 'hh24') --+ 1/24
GROUP BY r.time1
ORDER BY r.time1;
```

If 01:12 AM means 02:00 AM in result, then omit the comment code.

Reference: [Generating Dates between two date ranges_AskTOM](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:14582643282111)

Edited: For OP, you only need this:

```
WITH time_range AS 
(
    SELECT TRUNC(sysdate, 'hh24') - 23/24 + (ROWNUM - 1) / 24 AS time1
    FROM all_objects
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 24
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(r.time1, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi AM') AS date1,
    COUNT(t.systemdate) AS txncount
FROM time_range r
LEFT JOIN transactionlog t
ON r.time1 = TRUNC(t.systemdate, 'hh24') --+ 1/24
GROUP BY r.time1
ORDER BY r.time1;
```

Comment: @Phan X. Bach .. this ^ is not giving result for each hour in last 24 hours

Comment: @Sana.91 this IS giving result for each hour in last 24 hours. Copy and run it.

Comment: Regardless if it does or not, it has datetimes hardcoded. That is not an elegant solution.

Comment: @FDavidov What part did you see datetime hardcoded?

Comment: The 5 selects within the definition of `transactionlog`.

Comment: @FDavidov How on Earth? Did you read OP's question? `transactionlog` is the data table. That is sample data in a `CTE` to test my query. The solution only begin from `, time_range AS`, if you know what a `CTE` means

Comment: You mean **COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION**? No, would you care to explain it to me? Besides, you may wish to check a comment I added after the original question that explains a very simple solution approach.

Comment: @FDavidov If you can not read and understand a query, please don't go to `sql` tag and spam. And your "very simple solution approach" is good, you only need to enhance it to achive this: `if no record exist in that particular hour, 0 is shown`.

Comment: @Pham X. Bach how can i make it generic w.r.t current date time rather than hard coded date time

Comment: @Sana.91 See my edited answer. You only need the part from `With time_range AS`. Time range is calculated from `sysdate`, you could change `sysdate` to any date you want.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach, you should assume that I perfectly read code, even when written without care (I normally ignore questions with poorly presented code pieces as I believe the OP should easy the reading process). Still, your suggestion (don't get into SQL) was noted. Just don't be surprised to find my name again.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach it returns TXNCOUNT = 1 for the hour in which no transaction was performed..
I suppose since LEFT JOIN is used .. it should have returned 0!

Comment: @Sana.91 Yes, you should change `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(t.systemdate)`. Edited my answer.

Comment: Bad idea to use all_objects. I modified the statement for my purpose and all_rows did not have enough rows. You better use CONNECT BY LEVEL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a last 24 hours **calendar table**,then `LEFT JOIN`  **calendar table** by Original table.

1. `count(t.systemdate)` need to count `t.systemdate` because `t.systemdate` might be `NULL`
2. `connect by` create last 24 hours calendar table
3. `on` clause  `TO_CHAR(t.systemdate,'YYYY/MM/DD hh24','nls_language=american')` make sure the dateformat language are the same.

You can try this.

```
WITH Hours as 
(
  select sysdate + (level/24) dates
  from dual 
  connect by level <= 24
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(h.dates,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') AS dateHour, count(t.systemdate) AS totlecount
FROM Hours h
LEFT JOIN transactionlog t
on TO_CHAR(t.systemdate,'YYYY/MM/DD hh24','nls_language=american') 
    = TO_CHAR(h.dates,'YYYY/MM/DD hh24','nls_language=american')
GROUP BY h.dates
ORDER BY h.dates
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73db7/2*

---

**CTE Recursive**  Version

You can also use **CTE Recursive** to write a calendar table

```
WITH Hours(dates,i) as 
(
   SELECT sysdate,1 
   FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT sysdate + (i/24),i+1
   FROM Hours
   WHERE i<24
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(h.dates,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') AS dateHour, count(t.systemdate) AS totlecount
FROM Hours h
LEFT JOIN transactionlog t
on TO_CHAR(t.systemdate,'YYYY/MM/DD hh24','nls_language=american') 
    = TO_CHAR(h.dates,'YYYY/MM/DD hh24','nls_language=american')
GROUP BY h.dates
ORDER BY h.dates
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73db7/7*